# Помогите с заданием!

Tags: синтаксис

Найди лишнее в каждой группе и объясни почему:

1. А.  Сытый голодного не разумеет
   Б. Я помню чудное мгновенье
   В. Люблю грозу в начале мая.

Думаю, здесь В, т.к. оно односоставное, хотя какое подлежащее в первом (сытый?)

2. А.Мороз и солнце;день чудесный.
   Б. Кругом не было ни души.
   В. Чему быть, того не миновать.

Лишнее А, т. к. односоставное именное (или день чудесный -это сказуемое?), остальные глагольные.

3. А. Дареному коню в зубы не смотрят
   Б. Люблю тебя, Петра творенье.
   В. От добра добра не ищут.

Здесь лишнее Б, т.к. оно определенно личное.

Comment: "Помогите с заданием!" Тут восклицательный знак означает требование?

Answer (score 1):

1. В. Люблю грозу в начале мая! ( определенно-личное.)Первые два предложения двусоставные.
2. А. Мороз и солнце; день чудесный! (назывное.)
   2-е предложение безличное, 3-е безличное.
3. Люблю тебя Петра творенье! (определенно-личное.)Остальные неопределенно-личные.

Answer (score 0):

Во второй группе два сложных предложения и одно простое, этим оно и отличается. Не уверен, что корректно сравнивать сложные предложения с простыми по другим критериям.

Comment: Но если тест по теме "Типы односоставных предложений", то вполне корректно.

Comment: @Людмила  Может и так. А может, тема более общая. К сожалению, нас опять приглашают поиграть в угадайку.